# Drawing circle in Google Earth around point?

Tags: google-earth

I can't seem to figure out how to draw a circle in Google Earth.

I'm trying to draw a 750km circle around Vancouver.

I'm trying to generate the kml file here:
    http://kml4earth.appspot.com/circlegen.html

But I can't seem to figure out the correct corrodents. 
I'm using:
    http://www.tageo.com/index-e-ca-v-02-d-m812033.htm

Answer (score 15):

Pro tip... use the measuring tool to draw circles!

Google Earth Pro's drawing tools do not include an easy way to draw accurate circles.  But, the ruler/measuring tool does let you measure circular areas and save them as KML, so you can do the following to draw a circle:

1. Open measuring tool (ruler icon on toolbar, or Tools menu > Ruler)
2. In Ruler window, select the "Circle" tab
3. Select the units you want to measure the radius in (eg: Kilometers)
4. Click (click, don't drag) on the map at the center point of your circle (eg: Vancouver)
5. Move your mouse until the circle radius is the distance you want (eg: 750km)
6. Click the map again to complete the circle
7. In the Ruler window, click the "Save" button
8. In the "New Path" window which appears, give it a name and click "Ok" button
9. Find your circle in the Places panel!

Comment: After doing this, is there a way to determine the coordinates of the centre of the circle shape?

Comment: @Ricky You see this coordinates on the screen, just turn on View > Status Bar.

Answer (score 6):

If I am not missing something obvious, latitude and longitude data in decimal degrees is found at the left hand side of the linked page, i.e. 49.667 and -125.833 respectively.

[image]

[image]

Comment: How do you get to the circle radius feature?

Answer (score 0):

Buffer it in QGIS and then take it back to Google Earth.

Answer (score 0):

The best results I have obtained was by using
[KML Circle Generator](https://kml-circle-generator.herokuapp.com/) by Fu Cheng. It's a little janky but it does the job.